# how does the text change color while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-transitions

I have been trying to work out how the text in the nav and the logo on this site 
http://www.tokiolab.it/ changes the colour as you scroll.

I can change the colour when you get to a different section easy enough but on this site there is a point when the text and the logo is half black and half white and vice versa as you scroll.

It seems to be using some kind of transparent background? Any ideas on how I can get this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is called: "parallax"

You'll notice on the tokiolab website they use the following images:

- http://www.tokiolab.it/img/en_nav_portfolio.png
- http://www.tokiolab.it/img/en_nav_contatti.png
- http://www.tokiolab.it/img/en_nav_mission.png

They are using a parallax like effect to put these images on different "layers" so when you scroll down it looks like the image is changing color when it's really just a different background image on another layer.

You can use some different plugins like these:

- http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/
- http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/
- http://www.davecranwell.com/content/jquery-scroll-parallax-plugin
- http://curtain.victorcoulon.fr/#intro
- http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Might take some tinkering but the top few can get you moving in the right direction!

Comment: Are you certain that's the issue here?  None of the linked pages seem to describe the OP's question.

Comment: Added more details, you'll see that the changing color is nothing more than images with a parallax effect.